# ¿Cómo establecer cual es la lista con mas elementos en Python?

Tags: python, lista

Estoy haciendo un programa en Python y tengo 3 listas y requiero saber cuál de las 3 tiene más elementos, y quisiera usar un método más simple que este:

```
lista_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lista_b = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lista_c = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

# Obtener la longitud de cada lista
longitud_a = len(lista_a)
longitud_b = len(lista_b)
longitud_c = len(lista_c)

# Comparar las longitudes
if longitud_a > longitud_b and longitud_a > longitud_c:
    print("La lista A tiene más elementos.")
elif longitud_b > longitud_a and longitud_b > longitud_c:
    print("La lista B tiene más elementos.")
elif longitud_c > longitud_a and longitud_c > longitud_b:
    print("La lista C tiene más elementos.")
else:
    print("Al menos dos listas tienen la misma cantidad de elementos o todas tienen la misma cantidad.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código no es fácil de simplificar si quieres ese tipo de salida y para solo tres listas. Si en vez de obtener una referencia a la lista mas larga quieres como salida algo similar a los prints de tu código, creo que tal como esta es correcto, simple, legible y optimizado (una sola llamada a `len` por lista, uso de `elif` en vez de encadenar `if`, etc). Muchos entienden por simplificar hacer lo mismo con menos código, pero eso no siempre es buena idea, no si implica reducir la legibilidad o incluso la eficiencia.

Dicho esto, usar un simple bloque condicional para obtener la lista con mayor numero de elementos tiene un problema; escala fatal. En cuanto añadamos alguna lista mas todo se vuelve complicado y poco legible. Si nos ceñimos solo a la pregunta:

> ¿Cómo establecer cual es la lista con mas elementos en Python?

quizás la forma mas simple y mas eficiente con diferencia sea usar `max` y su argumento `key`:

```
>>> lista_mas_larga = max(lista_a, lista_b, lista_c, key=len)

>>> lista_mas_larga
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

el problema (o no, todo depende de lo que busquemos) es que si tenemos varias listas con la longitud mayor, esto retorna la primera encontrada con esa longitud. Si quisiéramos todas las listas con la longitud máxima, podríamos implementar algo como:

```
def obtener_listas_mas_largas(*listas):
    if not listas:
        return ()
    longs = [len(lista) for lista in listas]
    max_long = max(longs)
    return tuple(lista for lista, long in zip(listas, longs) if long == max_long)
```

---

```
>>> lista_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> lista_b = [2, 3, 7, 5, 11, 13]
>>> lista_c = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lista_d = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

>>> obtener_listas_mas_largas(lista_a, lista_b, lista_c, lista_d)
([2, 3, 7, 5, 11, 13], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```